# jQuery $.getJSON() not sending value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

The first File is: **`form.php`**.

I can't send the values (1 or 2) to my other file.

Can anyone help me out?

```
$(function () {
    $('#cod_cidades').change(function () {
        if ($(this).val()) {
            $('#s').hide();
            var valor = ($(this).val());
            $('.carregando').show();
            $.getJSON('vara.ajax.php', { cod_cidades: $(this).val(), ajax: 'true' }, function (j) {
                var options = '<option value=""></option>';
                for (var i = 0; i < j.length; i++) {
                    options += '<option value="' + j[i].s + '">' + j[i].nome + '</option>';
                }
                $('#s').html(options).show();
                $('.carregando').hide();
            });
        } else {
            $('#s').html('<option value="">– Escolha um estado –</option>');
        }
    });
});
```

**`Varas.ajax.php`**

This is the part that i get the value.

```
$id_cidade = mysql_real_escape_string( $_REQUEST['cod_cidades'] );
```

Comment: Please don't use `mysql_*` functions. Not good.

Comment: Looks perfect for me.

Comment: What's happening in the Console?

Comment: No errors? Or what? Any request going? Keep your console open and check.

Comment: Instead of `$_REQUEST[]` does `$_GET` have the contents? Maybe it's disabled in `php.ini`?

Comment: If i change to $.get shows "undefined"

Comment: there is this error "unreachable code after statement" on console

Comment: db connection (and query) is what, `mysql_`? `mysqli_`? PDO? other? could be relevant.

Comment: mysqli, I don't thin that this is the problem.

Comment: @NagibMatni That's not the problem. Just a tip.

Comment: *"mysqli, I don't thin that this is the problem."* - Err... yes that is a problem, if not **THEE** problem. `mysql_real_escape_string()` does NOT mix with `mysqli_` and `mysql_real_escape_string( $_REQUEST['cod_cidades'] )` will never populate and is probably why your code is failing.

Comment: You were right i'm so dumb

Comment: would you like me to submit that as answer to close this then? seeing I got this one ;-)

Comment: actually, seeing that I was the one to spot the problem, you should be accepting my answer ;-) as posted below. @NagibMatni http://stackoverflow.com/a/34832655/1415724 which is pretty much how Stack rolls ;-)

Answer (score 0):

"mysqli, I don't thin that this is the problem." - Err... yes that is a problem, if not THEE problem. mysql_real_escape_string() does NOT mix with mysqli_ and mysql_real_escape_string( $_REQUEST['cod_cidades'] ) will never populate and is probably why your code is failing. Fred -ii- 7

Answer (score 0):

This (and I had a feeling that's what the problem was) *"Spidey sense tingling"*.

```
mysql_real_escape_string( $_REQUEST['cod_cidades'] )
```

and you mentioned in comments that you are using `mysqli_` to connect with, after my asking you about it.

That MySQL function does not mix with `mysqli_`.

You need to use its `mysqli_` equivalent:

```
mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_REQUEST['cod_cidades'] )
```

You will need to change the `$connection` variable to match the one you are using.